# Creating a zero-filled pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is the best way to create a zero-filled pandas data frame of a given size?

I have used:

```
zero_data = np.zeros(shape=(len(data),len(feature_list)))
d = pd.DataFrame(zero_data, columns=feature_list)
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: No, I can't think of any substantial improvement on that.

Comment: I am getting a Memory Error on np.zeros, as the data is a big set. Any hints on what I can do? I got no other output apart from "MemoryError". I have 100GB of RAM and the data is just 20GB but still fails. No idea how to debug it, 64bit ubuntu server. I googled for a bit but everyone says - divide in to chunks, but this data can't be divided.

Comment: Can you just work with `data`? Why do you need to create another structure to hold it?

Answer (score 212, accepted):

Create and fill a pandas dataframe with zeros

```
feature_list = ["foo", "bar", 37]
df = pd.DataFrame(0, index=np.arange(7), columns=feature_list) 
print(df)
```

which prints:

```
   foo  bar  37
0    0    0   0
1    0    0   0
2    0    0   0
3    0    0   0
4    0    0   0
5    0    0   0
6    0    0   0
```

Comment: Testing this I find `%timeit temp = np.zeros((10, 11)); d = pd.DataFrame(temp, columns = ['col1', 'col2',...'col11'])` takes 156 us.
But `%timeit d = pd.DataFrame(0, index = np.arange(10), columns = ['col1', 'col2',...'col11'])` takes 171 us. I'm surprised it's not any faster.

Comment: Note that you may run into int/float issue if you will be doing something like `d.set_value(params)` after initializing `d` to contain 0's. An easy fix is: `d = pd.DataFrame(0.0, index=np.arange(len(data)), columns=feature_list)`.

Answer (score 50):

It's best to do this with numpy in my opinion

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
d = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((N_rows, N_cols)))
```

Comment: When I did it this way, I could not alter the "0" values. ```TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: @RightmireM How exactly are you trying to alter them? You are correct, the datatype is `np.float64`

Comment: `d = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((N_rows, N_cols))).astype("float32")` is quite memory efficient for larger size dataframe

Answer (score 21):

If you would like the new data frame to have the same index and columns as an existing data frame, you can just multiply the existing data frame by zero:

```
df_zeros = df * 0
```

If the existing data frame contains NaNs or non-numeric values you can instead apply a function to each cell that will just return 0:

```
df_zeros = df.applymap(lambda x: 0)
```

Comment: Be aware that you will get NaNs instead of zeros wherever df contains NaNs.

Answer (score 18):

Similar to @Shravan, but without the use of numpy:

```
  height = 10
  width = 20
  df_0 = pd.DataFrame(0, index=range(height), columns=range(width))
```

Then you can do whatever you want with it:

```
post_instantiation_fcn = lambda x: str(x)
df_ready_for_whatever = df_0.applymap(post_instantiation_fcn)
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming having a template DataFrame, which one would like to copy with zero values filled here...

If you have no NaNs in your data set, multiplying by zero can be significantly faster:

```
In [19]: columns = ["col{}".format(i) for i in xrange(3000)]                                                                                       

In [20]: indices = xrange(2000)

In [21]: orig_df = pd.DataFrame(42.0, index=indices, columns=columns)

In [22]: %timeit d = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros_like(orig_df), index=orig_df.index, columns=orig_df.columns)
100 loops, best of 3: 12.6 ms per loop

In [23]: %timeit d = orig_df * 0.0
100 loops, best of 3: 7.17 ms per loop
```

Improvement depends on DataFrame size, but never found it slower.

And just for the heck of it:

```
In [24]: %timeit d = orig_df * 0.0 + 1.0
100 loops, best of 3: 13.6 ms per loop

In [25]: %timeit d = pd.eval('orig_df * 0.0 + 1.0')
100 loops, best of 3: 8.36 ms per loop
```

But:

```
In [24]: %timeit d = orig_df.copy()
10 loops, best of 3: 24 ms per loop
```

**EDIT!!!**

Assuming you have a frame using float64, this will be the fastest by a huge margin! It is also able to generate any value by replacing 0.0 to the desired fill number.

```
In [23]: %timeit d = pd.eval('orig_df > 1.7976931348623157e+308 + 0.0')
100 loops, best of 3: 3.68 ms per loop
```

Depending on taste, one can externally define nan, and do a general solution, irrespective of the particular float type:

```
In [39]: nan = np.nan
In [40]: %timeit d = pd.eval('orig_df > nan + 0.0')
100 loops, best of 3: 4.39 ms per loop
```

Comment: This is definitely the most comprehensive answer on timing, although for the OP it seems that memory requirements were the issue and not speed... By the way, on my system the first two suggestion you wrote give the same timing (Pandas 0.20.3), so perhaps there have been some changes.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a dataframe, this is the fastest way:

```
In [1]: columns = ["col{}".format(i) for i in range(10)]
In [2]: orig_df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((10, 10)), columns=columns)
In [3]: %timeit d = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros_like(orig_df), index=orig_df.index, columns=orig_df.columns)
10000 loops, best of 3: 60.2 µs per loop
```

Compare to:

```
In [4]: %timeit d = pd.DataFrame(0, index = np.arange(10), columns=columns)
10000 loops, best of 3: 110 µs per loop

In [5]: temp = np.zeros((10, 10))
In [6]: %timeit d = pd.DataFrame(temp, columns=columns)
10000 loops, best of 3: 95.7 µs per loop
```