# how to create all zero dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a dataframe in Python with 24 columns (indicating 24 hours), which looks like this:

```
column name     0   1   2   3 ...   24

row 1           0   0   0   0        0
row 2           0   0   0   0        0
row 3           0   0   0   0        0
```

I would like to know how to initialize it? and in the future, I may add row 4, with all "0", how to do that? Thanks,

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22963263/creating-a-zero-filled-pandas-data-frame

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create an empty numpy array, convert it to a dataframe, and then add the header names.

```
 import numpy
 a = numpy.zeros(shape=(3,24))
 df = pd.DataFrame(a,columns=['col1','col2', etc..])
```

to set row names use

```
 df.set_index(['row1', 'row2', etc..])
```

if you must.

Comment: shouldn't a = numpy.zeros(shape(3,24)) ?

Comment: @DiegoAgher good point (corrected) The theory still holds though.

Answer (score 18):

There's a trick here: when DataFrame (or Series) constructor is passed a scalar as the first argument this value is propogated:

```
In [11]: pd.DataFrame(0, index=np.arange(1, 4), columns=np.arange(24))
Out[11]:
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  ...  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

[3 rows x 24 columns]
```

*Note: `np.arange` is numpy's answer to python's range.*