# Concatenate two pandas dataframes on a new axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes both with shape `(d, w)` , I need to concatenate these two into a new dataframe with shape `(2, d, w)` (or even `(d, 2, w)`). A naive way to do this is by [creating a zero-filled dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22963263/creating-a-zero-filled-pandas-data-frame) with the right size and then replacing the values. But I wonder if there's a better way to do this. `pandas.concatenate` doesn't seem to be able to add a new axis. Is there any other pandas functions for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataFrames are inherently two dimensional. It is possible to use [Panels](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Panel.html) for 3d data, but they are deprecated and should not be used at this point. The Pandas docs recommend using [xarray](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/) for this purpose now.

Building a 3d array out of DataFrames using xarray looks like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[5,6],[7,8]])

da = xr.DataArray([df1, df2])
```

You can also use a [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html) to get a multi-dimensional index into the 2d DataFrame if that works better for you.

Comment: Did not know that. thanx.